# Can't open or quit Finder

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, finder, mojave

I'm trying to open Finder, but every time I try I get this error message:

[image]

I've tried restarting my Macbook Pro as well as doing a "Relaunch" from "Force Quit Applications":

[image]

However, nothing happens when I try to force-quit the application, so I'm 'stuck' with a non-responsive Finder. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try booting in Safe Mode. If it's still the same, overlay the OS from Recovery [data should remain untouched]

Comment: You could also try applying the combo update installer from Apple of the version of macOS that you ALREADY have. So if you have 10.14.5. Do a search for "Combo update macos 10.14.5." and download it from Apple Support and install it. Combo updates often solve a multitude of issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in a terminal window:

```
killall Finder
```

or even

```
killall -9 Finder
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open activity monitor
2. Search finder
3. Select finder process

[image]

4. Select left most cross button (x)

[image]

5. Select force quit